# How to insert a subfigure in tikzposter with captions?

Tags: subfloats, tikzposter, a0poster

I am writing a poster of a0 size with the help of standard tikz poster template.

I have figures in `.tex` (LaTeX figure). How to include TeX figure and also how to use `subfigure` package? I try the following in my `fancytikzposter`. But it gives an error (It works fine in `article` or `report` class).

```
\begin{figure}[htp!]
\centering
\subfigure[Switching time]{
\input{dfplb_3_11.tex}
}
\subfigure[Magnetization trajectory]{
\input{tr_dfplb_3_11.tex}
}
\caption{First Pinned layer biasing in Double pinned layer.}
\label{fig:dfplb}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Looking at `tikzposter`, the `figure` environment we are all used to is not supported. Use `tikzfigure` provided by `tikzposter` along with the `subcaption` package. Package `subfigure` is obsolet for a decade.

Comment: would be nice to have an actual working example as how to implement this 'subcaption' package. I tried, but seem to have to use 'minipage' enviro. It does add 'a lot' of extra typing.

Comment: @Johannes_B. Can you give a working example of using `subcaption` with `tikzposter` class? I tried using `subfoat` within `tikzfigure` but it gives subfloat outside box error.

Comment: @chandresh Don't include it *inside* the tikzpicture.

Comment: Note that AFAIK `tikzpicture` and `tikzfigure` are two different things. `subfloat` requires environment to be placed which is `tikzfigure`. I am using `tikzposter` class that defines `tikzfigure` env. 'figure' env does not work in `tikzposter`.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu See below

Comment: @chandresh See below.

Answer (score 2):

The class does some questionable things and the current behaviour should be mended, imho.

As already noted, use package `subcaption` achieve the result.

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzfigure}{\captionsetup{type=figure}}
\begin{document}
\block{Busy bee}{
    \begin{tikzfigure}[bumble bee]
        \subcaptionbox{Laly Leguan}{%
            \rule{8cm}{6cm}
        }
        \subcaptionbox{}{
            \rule{8cm}{6cm}
        }
    \end{tikzfigure}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I achieved the same thing using minipage trick to put figures side-by-side. Anyways, Thanks for your effort.